# Is $(S^{1} \setminus \{1\}) \sqcup \{1\}$ homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology

Is the disjoint union of $S^{1} \setminus \{1\}$ and the singleton $\{1\}$ homeomorphic to $S^1$? My intuition tells me it is, just trying to be sure…

Comment: How are you defining the topology on $(S^{1} \setminus \{1\}) \sqcup \{1\}$?

Comment: $\{1\}$ is not an open set in the disjoint union space. (We tend to call the disjoint union of topological spaces the coproduct.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disjoint union is disconnected whereas the circle is connected

Comment: My guess is that you meant circle rather than sphere.